# How to deal with worn-out USB port?

Tags: usb

I have a Sony VAIO, about 5 years old, where the USB port that I use for the mouse is wearing out and making a poor/intermittent connection.  I transport the unit back and forth to work every workday, and so there are two connect/disconnect cycles a day, leading to the wear.

Thankfully, the unit has two other USB ports, but is there any good way to "rescue" the worn one?  Is it likely that my friendly local computer repair hack can replace the port?  Is there any sort of standard repair device/scheme for this?

Note that any scheme that leaves something projecting out more than 1/4" or so would not allow the unit to be "bagged" for transport and is a non-starter.

Comment: SOme places might, but its uncommon. I know a repair shop with a soldering setup on their front desk - its a reasonably standard part.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only used for a mouse, get a wireless mouse with a stay in port dongle.  Some are almost flush.  Logitech Unifying type dongles are flush.  If you want to generally refurb the port you can try chemicals like DeOxit to clean the connectors and there is supposed to be a companion chemical to shield the gold conductors and provide a little bit of lubrication so there isn't so much mechanical wear.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with compressed air to clean out any dust/debris in the port, and possibly electrical contact cleaner to further clean the connections.  (Of course do all of this with power off and battery/AC power removed.)

Edit: can you tell if the USB cable is entering the port cleanly and seated properly? I.e. does it wiggle around or stay snug when inserted?  If the port is bent or physically damaged the above will probably not help.  As for replacement, I believe it is possible but do not have personal experience with that option.

Answer (score 0):

It is about time you upgrade your laptop! 5 years of heavy duty work (moving it around back and forth, plugging in cables and unplugging every day) is about as good as it gets.
If you want to save your ports a little more, you should be looking into getting a docking station or you can ask your computer supplier to install new USB ports (can be expensive!).
Worn-out ports, whether it's USB, Firewire, ethernet, or whatever else, are like worn-out tires on a car. You can't fix them. You either replace the tires, or you replace the car... 
And keep in mind for the next laptop, the same use of your USB's is going to cause the same problem. Hardware these days isn't made to last anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to *slightly* bend the springs inside the socket. This should make the contact stronger.

They are clearly visible on the *socket* (the right USB cable) on this picture:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Male_and_Female_USB_Connectors.jpg

(Of course laptop has to be powered down and without battery).
Do not bend the springs to and fro because they will break.